# the inet/inet6 line of ip a output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ip

I'm trying to understand the output of `ip a` command.

For example we can get this output from it:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
     link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
　　　inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
     inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000 
     link/ether 00:15:5d:4c:26:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
     inet 172.21.254.173/20 brd 172.21.255.255 scope global eth0 
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
     inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe4c:2618/64 scope link 
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

What I want to learn is about the inet and inet6 info.

I've studied they are the info of IPv4 and IPv6, then it says IP address (and broadcast address) and scope.

But I can't find the document of the contents after scope info. For instance, `lo` after `inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host`.

I've seen it might have additional info like `dynamic`.

Does anyone know any documents about them?

(In addition, I don't know why the end of the inet line says the interface name while the inet6 line not)

Thank you!

Comment: "_Does anyone know any documents about them?_" makes your question off-topic. However, I've answered it anyway using tools that should be already available as standard on your system. This may help you in the future to know how to find information about commands.

Answer (score 2):

`man ip` will give you a headline document about the `ip` command. At the end it gives cross-references ("SEE ALSO") such as `ip-address` to find out more about the `ip address` command.

If you look in that document with `man ip-address` you will find references to the scope, such as this one:

> ```
> IFADDR := PREFIX | ADDR peer PREFIX [ broadcast ADDR ] [ anycast ADDR ] [ label LABEL ] [ scope SCOPE-ID ]
>
> SCOPE-ID := [ host | link | global | NUMBER ]
> ```

Searching further down the same manual page will define `SCOPE` as follows

> **`scope SCOPE_VALUE`** the scope of the area where this address is valid.  The available scopes are listed in file `/etc/iproute2/rt_scopes`. Predefined scope values are:
>
> - `global` - the address is globally valid.
> - `site` - (IPv6 only, deprecated) the address is site local, i.e. it is valid inside this site.
> - `link` - the address is link local, i.e. it is valid only on this device.
> - `host` - the address is valid only inside this host.

The second part of your question is answered by the definition of a `link` type address.

Comment: Thanks for your really helpful answer!

Comment: The scopes listed above are for unicast   There are additional scopes for IPv6 multicast.

Comment: Do you have the list of the options for IPv6 multicast?

Answer (score 2):

The IPv6 link-local addresses in particular are peculiar in that the same address range is used, as part of normal operation, on each and every IPv6 link. The part where it says `scope link` underlines that the link-local address `fe80::215:5dff:fe4c:2618/64` is only valid on `eth0`, it wouldn't be a valid address for the host on some other network interface. (In fact, the same address might be used by some other host on some other link, though that would be rare given how the addresses are usually assigned based on the MAC address.)

This is unlike global addresses, which are valid on all links and interfaces.

See e.g. the sections "Address scopes" and "Scoped literal IPv6 addresses (with zone index)" in the [Wikipedia page "IPv6 address"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address)

Comment: @roaima, @ilkkachu
Do you know why the interface name is displayed after the scope info only on inet instead of inet6?
I'm still not sure the difference between `scope host lo` on inet line and `scope host` on inet6 line, I took a look `man` command and wiki @ilkkachu gave me.

Answer (score 2):

I will attempt to answer part of your question where you mention:

"I don't know why the end of the inet line says the interface name while the inet6 line not"

inet (or ipv4) seems to list the interface name for historical reasons.  This seems to have something to do with "alias" interfaces, which used to be used when you wanted more than one address on a single interface.  Linux can now support multiple IP addresses on a single interface without aliases, but in the past that was not the case.  Interface aliases are still around for backward compatibility.

inet6 (or ipv6) does not use that (alias) information.  Or more precisely, the Linux kernel netlink interface does not report the interface name (IFA_LABEL) when being queried for interface inet6 address information.

Note that I'm using the tags you associated with your question to assume that you are using Linux from a Ubuntu distribution.
The command `ip address show` (or `ip a` as you put it), comes from the *iproute2* package.  That command gets network interface and network address information from the Linux kernel via the netlink feature.

Using the command `man 7 rtnetlink` (or ref https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html) will provide some information regarding the netlink interface and where IFA_LABEL fits in.

The book "Understanding Linux Network Internals" says the following about ifa_label: "A string used mostly for backward compatibility with 2.0.x kernels that allowed aliased interfaces with names such as eth0:1".

The following link (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/alias.html) also described the Linux ip aliasing feature as historic but still around for backwards compatibility.

If you want to get even deeper into the details (which might be more appropriate for StackOverflow instead of UnixLinux), you can look for a line that has "if (rta_tb[IFA_LABEL])", in the file ip/ipaddress.c from the source code of "ip address show" (iproute2).  You will see that if the command receives IFA_LABEL information from the kernel, then it will print it as output of the command.

As pointed out by others, the man page for ip and ip-address can provide additional information for some of the other values that you can see in the output following inet and inet6.

This is my understanding of how this works, and others may have additional / better information.